# htlatex changes \textasciigrave to "Left Single Quotation Mark" (&#8216;)

Tags: htlatex

To display grave accents correctly in DVI and PDF I use `\textasciigrave`. But `htlatex` changes this to `&#8216;` (Left Single Quotation Mark). Is this a bug? (I use texlive 2015.)

For example

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\textasciigrave
\end{document}
```

processed with `latex` or `pdflatex` yields a correct grave accent glyph but process with `htlatex` gives `&#8216;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `tex4ht` support for `textcomp`. Try to save following file as `tcrm.htf`:

```
tcrm 0 246
'&#xF6CE;'  ''  Grave
'&#xF6C9;'  ''  Acute
'&#xEA15;'  ''  Circumflex
'&#xEA44;'  ''  Tilde
'&#xF6CB;'  ''  Dieresis
'&#xF6CF;'  ''  Hungarumlaut
'&#xEA40;'  ''  Ring
'&#xF6CA;'  ''  Caron
'&#xEA02;'  ''  Breve
'&#xF6D0;'  ''  Macron
'&#xEA30;'  ''  Dotaccent
'&#x00B8;'  ''  cedilla
'&#x02DB;'  ''  ogonek
'&#xEB56;'  ''  quotesinglbase.ts1
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#xEB52;'  ''  quotedblbase.ts1
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#xD80C;'  ''  twelveudash
'&#xF6DE;'  ''  threequartersemdash
''  ''  afii61664.cap
'&#x2190;'  ''  arrowleft
'&#x2192;'  ''  arrowright
'&#xEB65;'  ''  tieaccentlowercase
'&#xEB63;'  ''  tieaccentcapital
'&#xEB66;'  ''  tieaccentlowercase.new
'&#xEB64;'  ''  tieaccentcapital.new
''  ''  none
''  ''  afii61664.asc
'&#x2422;'  ''  uni2422
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#x0024;'  ''  dollar
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#x0027;'  ''  quotesingle
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#x2217;'  ''  asteriskmath
''  ''  none
'&#x002C;'  ''  comma
'&#xEB31;'  ''  hyphendbl
'&#x002E;'  ''  period
'&#x2044;'  ''  fraction
'&#xF730;'  ''  zerooldstyle
'&#xF731;'  ''  oneoldstyle
'&#xF732;'  ''  twooldstyle
'&#xF733;'  ''  threeoldstyle
'&#xF734;'  ''  fouroldstyle
'&#xF735;'  ''  fiveoldstyle
'&#xF736;'  ''  sixoldstyle
'&#xF737;'  ''  sevenoldstyle
'&#xF738;'  ''  eightoldstyle
'&#xF739;'  ''  nineoldstyle
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#x2329;'  ''  angleleft
'&#x2212;'  ''  minus
'&#x232A;'  ''  angleright
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#x2127;'  ''  uni2127
''  ''  none
'&#x25CB;'  ''  circle
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#x2126;'  ''  Omega
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#x301A;'  ''  uni301A
''  ''  none
'&#x301B;'  ''  uni301B
'&#x2191;'  ''  arrowup
'&#x2193;'  ''  arrowdown
'&#x0060;'  ''  grave.ts1
''  ''  none
'&#xEB09;'  ''  born
'&#x26AE;'  ''  divorced
'&#xEB16;'  ''  died
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#xEB40;'  ''  leaf
'&#x26AD;'  ''  married
'&#x266A;'  ''  musicalnote
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#xEB67;'  ''  tildelow
'&#xEB32;'  ''  hyphendbl.alt
'&#xEB0A;'  ''  breve.ts1
'&#xEB0D;'  ''  caron.ts1
'&#xEB2E;'  ''  hungarumlaut.ts1
'&#xEB15;'  ''  dblgrave.ts1
'&#x2020;'  ''  dagger
'&#x2021;'  ''  daggerdbl
'&#x2016;'  ''  uni2016
'&#x2030;'  ''  perthousand
'&#x2022;'  ''  bullet
'&#x2103;'  ''  uni2103
'&#xF724;'  ''  dollaroldstyle
'&#xF7A2;'  ''  centoldstyle
'&#x0192;'  ''  florin
'&#x20A1;'  ''  colonmonetary
'&#x20A9;'  ''  uni20A9
'&#x20A6;'  ''  uni20A6
'&#xEB2B;'  ''  guarani
'&#x20B1;'  ''  peso
'&#x20A4;'  ''  lira
'&#x211E;'  ''  recipe
'&#x203D;'  ''  uni203D
'&#xEB29;'  ''  gnaborretni
'&#x20AB;'  ''  dong
'&#x2122;'  ''  trademark
'&#x2031;'  ''  uni2031
'&#xEB4C;'  ''  paragraph.alt
'&#x0E3F;'  ''  uni0E3F
'&#x2116;'  ''  afii61352
'&#x2052;'  ''  discount
'&#x212E;'  ''  estimated
'&#x25E6;'  ''  openbullet
'&#x2120;'  ''  uni2120
'&#x2045;'  ''  uni2045
'&#x2046;'  ''  uni2046
'&#x00A2;'  ''  cent
'&#x00A3;'  ''  sterling
'&#x00A4;'  ''  currency
'&#x00A5;'  ''  yen
'&#x00A6;'  ''  brokenbar
'&#x00A7;'  ''  section
'&#xEB17;'  ''  dieresis.ts1
'&#x00A9;'  ''  copyright
'&#x00AA;'  ''  ordfeminine
'&#xEB0F;'  ''  copyleft
'&#x00AC;'  ''  logicalnot
'&#x2117;'  ''  uni2117
'&#x00AE;'  ''  registered
'&#xEB43;'  ''  macron.ts1
'&#x00B0;'  ''  degree
'&#x00B1;'  ''  plusminus
'&#x00B2;'  ''  twosuperior
'&#x00B3;'  ''  threesuperior
'&#xEB02;'  ''  acute.ts1
'&#x00B5;'  ''  mu
'&#x00B6;'  ''  paragraph
'&#x00B7;'  ''  periodcentered
'&#x203B;'  ''  uni203B
'&#x00B9;'  ''  onesuperior
'&#x00BA;'  ''  ordmasculine
'&#x221A;'  ''  radical
'&#x00BC;'  ''  onequarter
'&#x00BD;'  ''  onehalf
'&#x00BE;'  ''  threequarters
'&#x20AC;'  ''  Euro
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#x00D7;'  ''  multiply
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
''  ''  none
'&#x00F7;'  ''  divide
tcrm 0 246
```

(you need to add blank line at the end, Stackexchange eats it unfortunately).

From my quick test it provides correct unicode characters for `textcomp` glyphs, but further testing would be nice. I will post this as bug fix to `tex4ht` issue tracker if everything is OK.

[image]

Comment: This yields `&#xEB2A;` which is an unknown unicode glyph?

Comment: @user3224237 you are right, wrong unicode character was used, it should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Historically, the grave character (0x60) was rendered as a left single quote. In LaTeX, this still occurs in some situations. For example, `\textasciigrave` from the package `textcomp` is displayed as a quote using `latex` with Evince as viewer on my machine, however with xdvi it is displayed as grave and with `pdflatex` and Evince it is also a grave. The choice of `htlatex` to render a quote is therefore strictly speaking not a bug, but it is a bit of an odd choice given modern conventions.

A solution is to modify `htlatex`/`tex4ht` character mappings, but it is probably easier to use an alternative in your LaTeX source that renders as a grave accent in both dvi/pdf and `htlatex` output. On my system the literal backtick or glyph 18 work well. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item textcomp grave: \textasciigrave
\item amssymb backprime: $\backprime$
\item escape literal backtick: \`{}
\item math mode backtick: $`$
\item glyph 18: \symbol{18}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```